# Currency symbol not working in tikzpicture

Tags: nodes, tikz-pic

I want to create a currency exchange graph as shown with currency symbol instead of wordings in nodes.[image]

and this is the original code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \nodename/\x/\y in {GBP/0/4, USD/6/0, EUR/0/-4, MYR/-6/0}
    \node (\nodename) at (\x,\y) [shape=circle, inner sep=2pt, draw, thick {\nodename};

    \path[->,>=stealth,thick]
        (GBP) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.75] {1.14} (EUR)
        (EUR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.75] {0.88} (GBP)
        (GBP) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {5.35} (MYR)
        (MYR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {0.19} (GBP)
        (GBP) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {1.34} (USD)
        (USD) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {0.74} (GBP)
        (EUR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {1.18} (USD)
        (USD) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {0.85} (EUR)
        (EUR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {4.71} (MYR)
        (MYR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {0.21} (EUR)
        (USD) edge [bend left=10] node[fill=white, pos=0.7] {3.99} (MYR)
        (MYR) edge [bend left=10] node[fill=white, pos=0.7] {0.25} (USD);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A digraph showing exchange rates between US Dollar (USD), Ringgit Malaysia (MYR), Pounds (GBP), and Euro (EUR).}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So I changed all the `GBP` to `\pounds`, `EUR` to `\euro` (with `\usepackage{eurosym}`), `MYR` to `RM`, and `USD` to `\$` in the code and it's not working.

Is there anything wrong within the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it works, just not as node name. You were using `\nodename` twice, once to give the nodes names. There you cannot use symbols. And you were using `\nodename` for the contents of the nodes, where symbols are fine. All you need to do is to disentangle the two.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
   \foreach \X/\x/\y/\Symb in
   {GBP/0/4/\pounds,USD/6/0/\$,EUR/0/-4/\euro,MYR/{-6}/0/RM}
    {\node (\X) at (\x,\y) [shape=circle, inner sep=2pt, draw, thick]
    {\Symb};
    }

    \path[->,thick]
        (GBP) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.75] {1.14} (EUR)
        (EUR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.75] {0.88} (GBP)
        (GBP) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {5.35} (MYR)
        (MYR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {0.19} (GBP)
        (GBP) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {1.34} (USD)
        (USD) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {0.74} (GBP)
        (EUR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {1.18} (USD)
        (USD) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {0.85} (EUR)
        (EUR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {4.71} (MYR)
        (MYR) edge [bend left=12] node[fill=white, pos=0.5] {0.21} (EUR)
        (USD) edge [bend left=10] node[fill=white, pos=0.7] {3.99} (MYR)
        (MYR) edge [bend left=10] node[fill=white, pos=0.7] {0.25} (USD);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A digraph showing exchange rates between US Dollar (\$), 
Ringgit Malaysia (RM), Pounds (\pounds), and Euro (\euro).}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

an alternative way of drawing of the your diagram: without `\foreach` loop and with `edge quotes`. nodes are positioned by help of the library`positioning`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,positioning}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3 and 5,
every node/.style = {circle, draw, thick, minimum size=8mm, inner sep=2pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, thick, -stealth, bend left=12},
every edge quotes/.style={draw=none, fill=white}
                    ]
\node (MYR)                         {RM};
\node (GBP) [above right=of MYR]    {\pounds};
\node (USD) [below right=of GBP]    {\$};
\node (EUR) [below right=of MYR]    {\euro};
%
\draw   (GBP) edge [pos=0.75, "1.14"]   (EUR)
        (EUR) edge [pos=0.75, "0.88"]   (GBP)
        (GBP) edge ["5.35"]             (MYR)
        (MYR) edge ["0.19"]             (GBP)
        (GBP) edge ["1.34"]             (USD)
        (USD) edge ["0.74"]             (GBP)
        (EUR) edge ["1.18"]             (USD)
        (USD) edge ["0.85"]             (EUR)
        (EUR) edge ["4.71"]             (MYR)
        (MYR) edge ["0.21"]             (EUR)
        (USD) edge [pos=0.7, "3.99"]    (MYR)
        (MYR) edge [pos=0.7, "0.25"]    (USD);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A digraph showing exchange rates between US Dollar (\$),
Ringgit Malaysia (RM), Pounds (\pounds), and Euro (\euro).}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]